# Jquery image upload limit with multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image-uploading

I am using JavaScript to get the selected file extension when uploading image.But I want to set limit to upload only four images in one select.I have enabled the multiple attribute to select multiple images.How can I set limit to upload only four files at one time.My JavaScript code to get selected file extension is like :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fileupload').change(function(){
   var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
        alert("Please select an image.Only (gif, png, jpg, jpeg) types are allowed");
        return false;
      }
   });
});
```

My html form is like :-

```
<form method="POST">
  <input id="fileupload" class="image" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</form>
```

Comment: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ you can use this jQuery plugin for uploading multiple files..

Comment: My Upload functionality is working fine @Kartikeya Khosla.

Comment: Am using UploadHandler php class to upload images. @Lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can get from your question that you need to limit the number of files while uploading multiple files, you can validate that on client side using a small javascript. All you need is just to access the `length` property of the input box for uploading the images.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST">
    <input id="fileupload" class="image" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" />
    <div class="validation" style="display:none;"> Upload Max 4 Files allowed </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#fileupload').change(function(){
   //get the input and the file list
   var input = document.getElementById('fileupload');
   if(input.files.length>4){
       $('.validation').css('display','block');
   }else{
       $('.validation').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5M2Kq/)

Your other file name extension validation for letting only image files in upload remains the same.

Comment: But this will not prevent to select more than four images.This will only show the validation message .

Comment: I don't think there is a JavaScript solution for that..since it is based on the window selection..you have to set a flag to set the validation is failed and prevent the form submission by returning false..so make the client side validation and then make the ajax post call to make your Upload handler call for handling the files if validation is passed..

Comment: Thank for suggestion, I exactly did that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @lucky suggestion above and also add a disable button function to only show when such criteria has been met.

```
$('#fileupload').change(function(){
   //get the input and the file list
   var input = document.getElementById('fileupload');
   if(input.files.length>4){
       $('.validation').css('display','block');
       $('#someid').prop('disabled', true);
   }else{
       $('.validation').css('display','none');
   }
});
```